# How can I access properties with dynamic keys in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to write a pipeline for my query but I am stuck at one point, to be specific in this example, this is the document (message document that has embedded chat reference) Im trying to fetch:

```
{
  "_id": "M-1ea13520-7c30-4482-b5bf-2f8467aa1735",
  "chatId": "C-91772cdf-c10b-4faa-9536-98a65554356c",
  "chat": {
    "_id": "C-91772cdf-c10b-4faa-9536-98a65554356c",
    "participants": [
      {
        "id": "1000001",
        "lastSeen": {
          "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1696204800000"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "1000002",
        "lastSeen": {
          "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1646204800000"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "publishedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1696322511000"
    }
  },
}
```

The match query I want to do is:

```
{
  publishedAt: { $gt: ISODate('2023-10-02T00:00:00.000+00:00')}
}
```

but instead of hardcoding date this should be pointing to lastSeen value of a dynamically given user in this query, lets say for user 1000001. My question is, how can I fix this query and dynamically access the correct lastSeen timestamp based on the given user?